# Is this result of definite integral as the limit of a sum correct?

Tags: definite-integrals

I know that, $$\int_{a}^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{b-a}{n} \sum\limits_{r=1}^n f \left( a + r\left(\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right) \right)$$

Then using that, does the following result hold?

$$\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{r=g_1(n)}^{g_2(n)} f\left(\dfrac{r}{n}\right) = \int_{\lim\limits_{n\to ∞} \frac{g_1(n)}{n}}^{\lim\limits_{n\to ∞} \frac{g_2(n)}{n}} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x, $$
where $g_1,g_2 : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ and $g_1(n)≤g_2(n), \, \forall n$

(What are the conditions on $g_i(n)?$)

---

I vaguely recall studying something like that, for example:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{r=n}^{3n} f\left(\dfrac{r}{n}\right) = \int_{1}^{3} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I can't seem to find the "exact" result, so I have tried to reconstruct from what I can recall, so some details might be missing. Can anybody point me to that result? I know only one Youtube video that talks about this result but the video is not in English.

**Edit:** See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2274399/552998), for example. Although the answer to that question doesn't quite answer it but it's something.

Comment: Yes, all your Eqs.  are  correct.

Comment: @ZAhmed can you point me to some reference for this result, I've been looking for it since forever, do you know what it's called?

Comment: @ZAhmed I'm kind of surprised the result actually holds. For instance what happens if $g_1(n)= n$ and $g_2(n) =n^2$?

Comment: You may search by Riemann sum.

Comment: @ZAhmed Riemann sum leads me to the first definition. Not the result. I'm specifically asking source for the result.

Comment: g(n)/n should asymptotically a constant.

Comment: @ZAhmed are you saying $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{g_i(n)}{n} = L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$? Thank you kind sir, would you be kind enough to point me to where can I find this **particular** result? :)

Comment: These are actually natural extentions you may not find a Ref.

Comment: @ZAhmed Oh well that's sad. I've been trying to prove it for a while but with no luck :(