# Limit of partial Harmonic Sum as a bounded integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Can anyone explain why $(b,a)=(1,0)$ where $b-a=1$.

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{n+1} +\frac{1}{n+2} +...+\frac{1}{n+n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+i/n}=\int_a^b \frac{dx}{1+x}.$

How to determine $a$ and $b $ ?

According to book $b=1$ and $a=0$.

Comment: $1/n, 2/n, \ldots, n/n$ is a partition of which interval?

Comment: Found the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274399/explanation-for-how-limit-of-a-sum-can-be-converted-to-definite-integration?rq=1